# Kernel module to implement neighbour discovery

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ip, kernel-module

I have a requirement to implement a kernel module to perform a neighbour descovery and output the discovered details using `PRINTK`. I know that there are already existent modules to implement this feature such as `ARP` and `SEND - Secure Neighbor Discovery`. Also in Linux one can use `ip -6 neigh show` or `ip -4 neigh show` to perform this.

**My requirement** is to locate the code segment of the `kernel-module` which implements the `ip -6 neigh show` or `ip -4 neigh show` feature so that I could alter it to my requirements **OR** utilize these modules and develop my own kernel module to display the discovered neighbor the information on the console when I type the command `dmesg | tail`.

My research always lead to the already defined modules within the kernel and not on self implementing tutorials or examples. (https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=lldp+kernel+module&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=linux+neighbor+discovery+kernel+module+)

I would be really grateful if you experts would provide some assistance in this matter. MY project's success depend on this matter.

Thank you :)

Comment: net/core/neighbour.c http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.14.2/net/core/neighbour.c

Comment: @Sasi tahnk you very much for the reply.:) will it be possible to show which code segment gets executed when we parse the parameters `ip -6 neigh show` or `ip -4 neigh show`? I tried my best but could not find it after searching all night long. :(

Comment: @Hasita: Take look at iproute2 utility code (iproute2-3.14.0/ip/ipneigh.c do_show_or_flush) and see what type of request they sending to kernel from userspace. (it would be mostly net/core/neighbour.c neigh_dump_info)